# How to change icon of the pressed ImageButton dynamically in android?

Tags: android, button, imagebutton, android-button

Let me clarify the question.I have 4 Image Buttons,I want to change the icon of the pressed one and then if i press another Button so the next one should be changed and the last one should back to its previous icon.

Note : The example is Instagram . You see some Gray icons when you click each one, it turns to black . And when you click another one the last one turns to gray and the new one turns to black.

Comment: Use different drawables for different states of the button.

Comment: @SripadRaj I'm new to android programming can you give me an example ? :)

Comment: Can you check for this solution ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534076/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-a-button-group-that-can-be-selected-and-activate-inde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code for creating a xml file in drawable folder, and use that as an image drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_yellow"
              android:state_pressed="true" />
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_orange"
              android:state_focused="true" />
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_green" />
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_icon" android:state_selected="true"/>

  </selector>
```

and use different image, depending on the press state.

Comment: This code only change the icon color when you press it like half a sec . how do I keep the pressed color until i press some other icon ? like the Instagram .

Comment: Add one more state in the above code:

<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_orange"
              android:state_selected="true" />

and call 
   iv.setSelected(true); 
for the selected button and 
iv.setSelected(false);
for unselected button.
It will work.

Comment: I have added state selected and its still not working .

Comment: where should I put  .setSelected(true) and fals ?

Comment: b1.setSelected(true);  // For selected
    b2.setSelected(true);  // For un selected 
    b3.setSelected(true);
    b4.setSelected(true);

on the click of every button selected true active button and for other selected false.

Comment: I use setSelected for each onClick and set 1 true for the current btn and 3 false for the other icons . but still it turns the color into black when I put my finger in button and after i release it , it goes back to gray again . Where do i miss ?

Comment: Remove state_pressed if you don't want any effect on pressed.

Comment: I removed state_pressed and focused but still the pressed is not working :(
it only turns into black like a blink

Comment: well I see the problem . Actually i'm using imageButton with white back ground and then i use the android:src="@drawable/selector.xml" thats why nothing is going to change . do you have any idea how can i do this for imagebuttons ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CamTestActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button b1,b2,b3,b4;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        b4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);

        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
        b4.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id){

            case R.id.btn1:
                 pressbtn1();
                break;

            case R.id.btn2:
                pressbtn2();
                break;

            case R.id.btn3:
                pressbtn3();
                break;

            case R.id.btn4:
                pressbtn4();
                break;
        }

    }

    private void pressbtn4() {
        b1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_gray));
        b2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_gray));
        b3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_gray));
        b4.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_black));
    }

    private void pressbtn3() {
        b1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_gray));
        b2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_gray));
        b3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_black));
        b4.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_gray));
    }

    private void pressbtn2() {
        b1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_gray));
        b2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_black));
        b3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_gray));
        b4.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_gray));
    }

    private void pressbtn1() {
        b1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_black));
        b2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_gray));
        b3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_gray));
        b4.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_gray));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to change background color.I want to change the icon completely.There is 2 icons for each Button 1 is gray and 1 is black . I want to change the icon 1 into black when its clicked ( the rest gray ) and the icon 2 into black ( the rest Gray ) and so on .

Comment: AS i changed color.. you can change icon as well.
Like b1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_gray));

Answer (score 1):

**Java Code:**

```
    public void onAnyButtonCLick(View view)
    {

    for (int i = 0; i < parent_layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
          View v = parent_layout.getChildAt(i); 
    // Check v is button 
    if(v instanceof Button)
    {

     // set all button with grey color background
      v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_gray));

    }

    } // loop ends

    // color the current click button with black.
    view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_black));


    } // end of click
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2">



    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First Button"

        android:onClick="button_click"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Second Button"
        android:onClick="button_click"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Third Button"
        android:onClick="button_click"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Forth Button"
        android:onClick="button_click"/>

</LinearLayout>


// Hope it Helps !!
```