# how to prevent a user from clicking on a button after another button has been clicked?

Tags: android

I am new to android programming and am building a quiz app in which a question has 4 options and  if the user clicks on one of the options the other options should be unclickable. I am currently able to only make a single button unclickable. Here is the java code.

```
package com.example.android.quiz;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}




//This method is called when option 1 of question 1 is selected
public void verifyQuestion1Option1(View view) {
    Button QuestionOption1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.question1_option1);
    QuestionOption1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.solid_red));

    question1Answer();

}

public void verifyQuestion1Option2(View view) {
    Button Question1Option2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.question1_option2);
   Question1Option2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.solid_red));//solid red is not a predefined colour. It is declared in colors.xml

    question1Answer();

}

public void verifyQuestion1Option3(View view) {
    Button Question1Option3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.question1_option3);
    Question1Option3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.solid_green));

    question1Answer();

}

public void verifyQuestion1Option4(View view) {
    Button Question1Option4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.question1_option4);
    Question1Option4.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.solid_red));//We call the getResources() method because R.colour.solid_red passed the id of the color not the actual colour value.

    question1Answer();

}

public void question1Answer() {
    TextView q1Answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question1_answer);
    String answer = "Rajinish Kumar is the current Chairman of SBI who took over after Arundhati Bhattacharya retired on 6 October.Shikha Sharma is the Managing Director and CEO of Axis Bank and Chanda Kochhar is the managing director and CEO of ICICI Bank";
    q1Answer.setText(answer);
}

}
```

Comment: Disable others.

Comment: how? Should i make the button object global(but the app crashes if i make the objects global)

Comment: Define only `Button QuestionOption1;` globally. dont addd the initialization part.

Comment: Maybe this link will helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534076/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-a-button-group-that-can-be-selected-and-activate-inde

Comment: You can use radiobutton along with radiogroup

Comment: You can use radioButton inside radioGroup. But you will have to set radio button background according to your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.setEnabled(false);` to disable a button. That button will grey out and does not respond to click events any more.

To disable all buttons, get the handle to each button and set them to disabled.

```
Button Question1Option1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.question1_option1);    
Button Question1Option2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.question1_option2);
Button Question1Option3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.question1_option3);    
Button Question1Option4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.question1_option4);
Question1Option1.setEnabled(false);
Question1Option2.setEnabled(false);
Question1Option3.setEnabled(false);
Question1Option4.setEnabled(false);
```

That way, all buttons of this question become disabled.
You can also come up with a solution where you save that the button is already pressed and ignore further click events. You could introduce some sort of variable `bool question1answered = false;` that is set to true as soon as the onClick event is fired.

```
public void verifyQuestion1Option4(View view) {
  if (question1Answered == true) {return;}
  question1Answered =true;
  //Do the rest of your checks here

  }
```

Two tips for for programming Java:

1. Java (in contrast to i.e C#) used lower letter variables as convention.
   `Button question1Option1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.question1_option1);` would be a better way.
2. If you have more questions, it would make sense to put them in some sort of array and reuse the same four buttons multiple times. That would save you much programming overhead and code rewrites if you have to change something. And it keeps the code cleaner.

Comment: should i declare the buttons as global objects?

Comment: If you disable the buttons inside your verification method, there is no need to declare them globally.

Answer (score 2):

Either you can use a buttongroup which will have only 1 active button at any point of time or else, you need to disable other button programatically.

To disable the button you can use the following code:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setEnabled(false);
```